# How to set Asia/Kuala_Lumpur timezone while updating CURTIME and CURDATE

Tags: php, mysql, timezone

While updating `CURDATE()` and `CURTIME()` into a column, it updates wrong time and date. I want to change the existing Timezone into `Asia/Kuala_Lumpur`

here is my update script:

```
$sql="UPDATE smss SET msg='$msg', r_date=CURDATE(), r_time=CURTIME(), phone='$phone' WHERE p_n='$p_n' and (p_n=null or p_n='') and (phone=null or phone='')";
```

Answer (score 2):

To changing time zone , you have many solution.
simply execute below query to change default timezone:

```
$sql="SET GLOBAL time_zone = 'Asia/Kuala_Lumpur' " ;
```

And after that, execute your update.

> Warning:Mysql is deprecated, Use Mysqli. "According to you question tags".

Comment: $sql="UPDATE smss SET GLOBAL time_zone = 'Asia/Kuala_Lumpur' msg='$msg', r_date=CURDATE(), r_time=CURTIME(), phone='$phone' WHERE p_n='$p_n' and (p_n=null or p_n='') and (phone=null or phone='')"; ------------------------------>  when i put this code it's nothing update. please say any different method or provide correct  code if i am wrong